# Assertions vs exceptions for library API type checking

Tags: python

Python encourages duck typing over explicit type checking.  However, sometimes it is useful to explicitly check types.

When a Python library need to do type checking, should it use assertions or exceptions?

```
def foo(bar):
    assert isinstance(bar, str)

def foo(bar):
    if not isinstance(bar, str):
        raise TypeError
```

A library's API is a public API, and public APIs should explicitly raise exceptions.  However, it shouldn't be the responsibility of a library to do user input validation (unless it is a user input validation library), nor is it reasonable to expect a library to be designed to be "used incorrectly".  A program using a library isn't going to catch the TypeError exception; it would be fixed to instead call the library API with the right types.

Should library type checking be done with assertions instead of raising exceptions?

Comment: I think that `assert` should be used as a debugging/testing tool.  As a library consumer I would be surprised to see an assertion failure.  If I try `import collections; c = collections.defaultdict(1)` I get a TypeError exception rather than an assertion failure; why should a package outside of the standard library behave any different?

Comment: You should do what's best for your situation. Explicit type checking is often not needed but sometimes it's the best way to handle something. In that case I would recommend using `isinstance()` so you can raise your exception with a message that informs the user what went wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Assertion evaluation can be deactivated by running python with the `-O` command line option which can be good if you want to check things more extensively than you would in production.

Have a look at https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively - they know more than me and they say:

> Places to consider putting assertions:
>
> - checking parameter types, classes, or values
> - checking data structure invariants
> - checking "can't happen" situations (duplicates in a list, contradictory state variables.)
> - after calling a function, to make sure that its return is reasonable